# Weird characters when using emacs on a Mac

Tags: osx, fonts

I've been recently using a Mac more (usually I use Linux). I've noticed that some special characters look different in emacs when using a Mac and in emacs when using Linux.

Here is what it looks like on Linux (and how it's suppose to look like):

[image]

Here is what it looks like on Mac:

[image]

Notice specifically that the short arrows have turned into an arrow with a weird tail and the long arrows have turn into short arrows. I'm using the same `init.el` file in both systems.

I'm using the same init file on both systems and loading the following font:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Inconsolata" :height default-font-size)
```

Comment: Different fonts, no? Check what those chars look like in the font you're using.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I should be using the same font. I'm loading the same init file in both which sets the font. The font is Inconsolata, though checking online, it doesn't seem to include these special chars.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts do not always contain every character. Since Inconsolata does not include a glyph for either of those arrows, Emacs must fall back to other available fonts. Since the list of available fonts is different on your two computers, it should not be very surprising if it picks different alternates. Put point on one of the arrows and use `C-u C-x =` to show all the information Emacs knows about it. It will include the actual font used to render the character.

Comment: I've run `describe-char` produces the following results: on Linux `ftcrhb:-CYRE-Inconsolata-regular-normal-normal-*-17-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x28C)`, on Mac: `mac-ct:-*-Arima Koshi-medium-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-p-0-iso10646-1`. So, it seems that I'm missing some fonts, thank you.